# How to get NHibernate mapping info from an Entity/Object

Tags: nhibernate

Given an entity instance, how do I get mapping information like table name, identifier column name, number of columns, etc?

Answer (score 3):

[Configuration.GetClassMapping](http://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Cfg/Configuration.cs?r=4534#l297). [PersistentClass](http://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Mapping/PersistentClass.cs?r=4283) has all the mapping info. Examples of PersistentClass manipulation:

- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/05/01/Dynamic-Mapping-with-NHibernate.aspx
- http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2008/11/mapping-source-how-map-class-without.html

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to retrieve, during run time, mapping info of entities that is already mapped using regular hbm.xml. And I justfound ISessionFactory.GetClassMetadata().